# Problem with conversion from LyX to PDF

Tags: pdftex, lyx, pdf

I received this error message:

> !pdfTeX error: pdflatex.exe (file eufm7): Font eufm7 at 600 not found

Indeed I used `\mathfrak` which is written in this font.

Let me also paste the preamble before `\begin{document}`.

```
%% LyX 2.3.6.1 created this file.  For more info, see http://www.lyx.org/.
%% Do not edit unless you really know what you are doing.
\documentclass[english]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[latin9]{inputenc}
\usepackage{units}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{amssymb}

\makeatletter
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% Textclass specific LaTeX commands.
\theoremstyle{plain}
\newtheorem{thm}{\protect\theoremname}[section]
\theoremstyle{plain}
\newtheorem{lem}[thm]{\protect\lemmaname}
\theoremstyle{plain}
\newtheorem{cor}[thm]{\protect\corollaryname}

\makeatother

\usepackage{babel}
\providecommand{\corollaryname}{Corollary}
\providecommand{\lemmaname}{Lemma}
\providecommand{\theoremname}{Theorem}
```

What should I do? Thanks in advance.

Comment: What latex installation are you using? Can we see the preamble of the lyx document you are using? (might be easiest to export the lyx document to latex, and then look in the `.tex` fiel using a text editor. The preamble is the stuff before `\begin{document}`

Comment: your tex system should have the type1 version of this installed, in texlive that would be `/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/fonts/type1/public/amsfonts/euler/eufm7.pfb`

Comment: The preamble is empty. Edit: I converted to LaTeX, I'll show the used packages

Comment: The preamble cannot be empty, it at least contains something like `\documentclass{article}` and probably several `\usepackage{}`-commands. It may be that LyX does not show it to you by default, but **it is there**. Maybe look in the menus of LyX if you can find it - I never used that program so I do not know where to look.

Comment: seeing the latex file will not actually help in this case as the euler font tfm will be accessed from tex in the standard way, the issue is you do not have a complete tex distribution installed, and need to install the amsfonts using tlmgr or miketx or whatever system you are using

Comment: I use TexLive distribution

Comment: do you have the directory that I indicated above (with whatever your installation location is instead of `/usr/local/texlive/2021`)

Comment: Actually I fount Euler: `C:\texlive\2021\texmf-dist\tex4ht\ht-fonts\unicode\ams\euler`. But why LyX doesn't recognize it?

Comment: no that is not the format you need, as I asked do you have euler under the type1 font tree

Comment: OK found it: `C:\texlive\2021\texmf-dist\fonts\type1\public\amsfonts\euler`.  But do I have to install the fonts manually?

Comment: if that has eufm7.pfb then you have the fonts installed but your font  map may be wrong, try  `updmap-sys` to regenerate the font map

Comment: Where to write the updmap-sys?

Comment: @YoavAvidan `updmap-sys`  is not a file to write, is a  program to be executed to update de configuration file  (`updmap.cfg` file in my Linux, I guess that it will be the same in WIndows). . You should already have it as part of TeX Live. Open the command prompt (CMD), type the name of the program, press enter and read the output to check if it worked.

Comment: Could you add more details please?

Comment: Finally did it. The file directory is `C:\texlive\2021\bin\win32\updmap-sys`. I opened this file, then it was open in the command prompt and everything works. Thank you very much for all who helped. The topic can be closed.